# Factoring App trait

Tags: scala

I have an application that makes use of the `App` trait, and it's all working fine. But the `object` that inherits from `App` is getting a bit unwieldy, so I'd like to split some of the functionality out into traits. In particular, I'd like to split out the command-line argument handling.

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to play well with `DelayedInit`. So this works fine:

```
object Main extends App {
  println("arguments are: "+ args.mkString.mkString(", "))
}
```

but this throws a `NullPointerException`:

```
trait CommandLineArguments { this: App =>
  println("arguments are: "+ args.mkString.mkString(", "))
}

object Main extends App with CommandLineArguments
```

Is there any way to get `DelayedInit` to "include" mixed-in traits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks strange, if write some like this, works fine:

```
trait CommandLineArguments { self: App => 
  delayedInit {
     println("arguments are: "+ args.mkString.mkString(", "))
  }
}
```

But from scaladocs (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.DelayedInit):

> Classes and traits inheriting the DelayedInit marker trait will have
>   their initialization code rewritten as follows.*[Code] becomes delayedInit([Code])*
>   Initialization code comprises all statements and all value definitions
>   that are executed during initialization.